# What's the meaning of /*#__PURE__*/ in some javascript source code?

Tags: javascript

for example:

```
function _test() {
  _test = _asyncToGenerator(
    /*#__PURE__*/ regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee(args) {
      return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
        while (1) {
          switch ((_context.prev = _context.next)) {
            case 0:
            case "end":
              return _context.stop();
          }
        }
      }, _callee);
    })
  );
  return _test.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I both have tried google and baidu, but nothing helpful for me.

Comment: Github search works surprisingly well. Here's one of the results I found ~ https://github.com/semibran/html/blob/498282d26e1091857af5ef175218d0a3147e11d3/lib/html.js#L5

Comment: It indicates that the function is [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which is particularly meaningful when optimizing code. One mention of this: https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/520

Comment: https://medium.com/@LihauTan/dead-code-elimination-hint-uglify-js-that-your-function-is-pure-208efb251c7c

Comment: In case it wasn't clear by the existing answers, this `/*#__PURE__*/` thing is specific to webpack, to help it know how to optimize when bundling. From Javascript's perspective, `/*#__PURE__*/` is just a comment.

Comment: Another form: `/* @__PURE__ */`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's an indication that [the function in question is pure](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), or to be more precise, side-effect free. This helps with tree-shaking - the removal of dead code from bundles when nothing else references a particular value.

Just for example, if you have a function available, `foo`, and the result of calling `foo` isn't ever used in the project, eg

```
const x = 3;
foo();
const y = 4;
```

and `foo` is pure, then the line there doesn't do anything.

If all such calls to `foo` are never used, then code optimizers are free to remove the `foo` function completely (as well as everywhere it's called, if all such calls do not have their return value used).

Comment: So why do we need such a calling?

Comment: It's not *needed*, but it's *helpful* as an indicator for Webpack, to let it know that it can safely remove something if the result of a call to the pure function isn't used.

Comment: It’s especially useful when writing modular library code, where you can’t know which part of your lib a user will actually end up using within his own business code. Marking specific parts of your (side-effect free) code as PURE allows for tools such as uglify-js to drop those unused lib chunks from the user’s final build, hence reducing footprint etc.